# Spring Rest Validation ObjectNode data size limit

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, jackson, spring-validation

I have rest controller with token creation call. Here inside ObjectNode I get big json data. The database column is varchar2(4000) nad I want limit this ObjectNode size to 4000 adding validation at controller level. Not sure how to do this?

```
data class TokenRequest(
    @NotEmpty(message = "id is mandatory")
    open val id: String,
    @NotEmpty(message = "gameId is mandatory")
    open val game: String,
    @NotEmpty(message = "gameType is mandatory")
    open val type: String,
    @NotEmpty(message = "gameDate is mandatory")
    open val date: String,
    @NotEmpty(message = "coupon is mandatory")
    open val token: ObjectNode,
)
class TokenController {
fun createToken(@Valid @RequestBody request: TokenRequest): Token {
        val now = Token.generateNowTimestamp()
        val token = Token.fromTokenRequest(request, now, now, request.teamId)
        return tokenService.create(token)
    }
}
```